# Adding RestKit under project GIT repository

Tags: git, xcode5, restkit

I integrated RestKit to my project using CocoaPods.
The setup was simple enough, but I want to add the RestKit framework and its dependencies under my project repository, so when I push my local repo to a remote, the other developers can clone from the remote to have the whole project, with RestKit, set up for them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use a Git submodule and the associated submodule processes.

See [this guide](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule).

If you actually want to fully maintain your own copy of the code, which means breaking away from Git updates completely, then you need to download everything, delete all of the .git directories and check it into your repo.

Comment: Hi, I tried this as well. Once I add the submodule and configure my project as directed, I see that my project has 6 new working copies. How do I track all 6 working copies under one repo (these new working copies have github.com as their origin)?